# Opening multiple browsers with different username & click on different device

Tags: jmeter

Our application is a medical module & from the device we are getting continous ECG waveform & some vitals say Heart rate.

Application is using WebSocket protocol & the communication is happening via Signalr.

Using jmeter websocket plugin I am able to connect the device.

But unable to get the real time data as the ECG waveform is streaming continously.

For me its impossible to get the real time data via JMeter.

Is there any other way in Jmeter or except Jmeter, using which I can able to open multiple web browsers at a time & login with different user credentials & open live streaming page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler" and "jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config" for chrome to run multiple browser. Config will have the path for chrome driver exe and sampler will have the code for user operation. Then, thread group can be used for multi-threading/multi browser.

[image]

Similarly you can use for IE and Firefox.

Documentation: https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/

I have not used websocket but found below link.
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter

Hope this helps.